# Single phase induction Motor starting capacitor not disconnected

Tags: capacitor, induction-motor, single-phase

I have studied the single-phase induction motor and have a little confusion regarding it. I have seen many people using a switch with the phase shift starting capacitors so that after the start the capacitor is disconnected. I wanted to ask if there will be any problem if I do not remove the capacitor after starting. It continues pushing and I feel like it's convenient to use one capacitor instead of adding another run-time capacitor. Kindly tell me if this will cause any problems for me. Since I have seen that in ordinary fans there is one capacitor and it doesn't get disconnected as far as I have seen. I need to know if this is good practice or not. This question is a general one and not for a specific motor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the capacitor is not disconnected, the motor will keep running without any problems. The capacitor is incorporated to assist in the initial rotation during startup, and if it remains connected without being switched off, the only consequence would be energy loss.